# Why doesn't this method work to assign characters, in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, dom

Ok, here goes a newbie question:

```
//function removes characters and spaces that are not numeric.

// time = "2010/09/20 16:37:32.37"
function unformatTime(time) 
{       

    var temp = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    temp[0] = time[0];
    temp[1] = time[1];
    temp[2] = time[2];
    temp[3] = time[3];
    temp[4] = time[5];
    temp[5] = time[6];
    temp[6] = time[8];
    temp[7] = time[9];
    temp[8] = time[11];
    temp[9] = time[12];
    temp[10] = time[14];
    temp[11] = time[15];
    temp[12] = time[17];
    temp[13] = time[18];
    temp[14] = time[20];
    temp[15] = time[21];   


}
```

In FireBug I can see that the characters from time are not assigned to temp? 
Do i have to use a replace() function to do something like this in JS?

Thank You.

Comment: This makes me cry.

Comment: @Stefan Kendall: o come on, I am learning...

Comment: @Tommy, I don't think he was being *mean*, just making the point that it's a poor approach. Though perhaps it does come across as a little harsh. Still, even if your code induced tears you asked a better question (by documenting what you've already tried) than many. +1 for the question and comment.

Comment: @David Thomas: I understand and thank you for asking him to clarify his answer and helping out the "weak". haha

Comment: @Tommy: ah, you're welcome; it was purely for self-interest... =b

Comment: I was being harsh. I cried in the same way I cried when I saw another student trying to create 100 button objects manually in an effort to avoid arrays. It's good that you recognized that this was the wrong approach, however. That's more useful than a reasonably-good approach 9 times out of 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[^\d]` is the regular expression for "not digit".

In more detail,

`[]` represents a "character class", or group of characters to match on.
`\d` is a shortcut for `0-9`, or any digit.
`^` in a character class negates the class.

```
function unformat(t)
{
   return t.replace( /[^\d]/g, '' );
}
```

You can't access a string like that in one of the major browsers, anyway. You would need to use `str.charAt(x)`.

Comment: @Stefan, just because I still regard regex as being a dark art, could you talk me through what the `/[^\d]/, ''` does? O_o I suspect the OP, given his initial approach that made you cry, would probably appreciate this too...+1

Comment: @Stefan note that plain "\D" (no brackets) also means "not a digit".

Comment: Oh, and to be able to pass in any number of times and get an array of unformatted times returned, just make use of the `arguments` array instead of a written in argument ==> http://jsfiddle.net/3UW8e/

Answer (score 3):

You should definitely use a regular expression for this.

```
function unformatTime(time) {
    return time.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
}
```

In this case it looks for anything that is a non-digit and replaces with an empty string.  The 'g' at the end means "global" so it will replace as many times as it can.

- `^` This inside the bracket means "not"
- `\d` This means "digit"
- `g` This means "global"

Comment: Possibly a stupid question, but if `^` means 'not' and `\d` means 'not digit'...that's a double negative?

Comment: @Pointy: I believe it is the "^" that makes the \d negated. (See others have questions like this too) Checkout http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Comment: Yes, that'll work, but the Javascript regex syntax already has a built-in "not a digit" special character, and it's "\D" (backslash followed by capital 'D').

Comment: @David Thomas no, "\d" means "digit" and "\D" means "not a digit" - lower-case vs. capital. You use "\D" by itself, without the square brackets (just as one can use "\d" without square brackets to match a digit).

Comment: @Pointy, *ahhhh* I completely missed the case-change. ...and I only just *bought* these glasses =) (also, that right there is *probably* why I still find regex difficult to grasp...)